# Is a EOFException always caused by remote host?

Tags: java, spring, sockets

I have a client that sends data to a host via socket. Occasionally I get `java.io.EOFException`.

The question is: how can I know who caused the socket close? Is that exception always raised because the remote host closed the socket?

Or could it be as well an internal network connection problem? Or from my ISP?

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Dispatcher failed to deliver Message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Exception while awaiting reply; nested exception is java.io.EOFException: Connection is closed
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.wrapExceptionIfNecessary(AbstractDispatcher.java:133) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:120) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:150) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:42) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:97) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:38) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:37) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_131]

Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Exception while awaiting reply; nested exception is java.io.EOFException: Connection is closed
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway$AsyncReply.getReply(TcpOutboundGateway.java:322) ~[spring-integration-ip-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(TcpOutboundGateway.java:139) ~[spring-integration-ip-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler$AdvisedRequestHandler.handleRequestMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:178) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor980.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333) ~[spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice$1.execute(AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.java:75) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.invoke(AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.java:70) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1241.handleRequestMessage(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.doInvokeAdvisedRequestHandler(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:127) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:112) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    ... 21 more

Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Connection is closed
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory$1.run(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:682) ~[spring-integration-ip-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    ... 3 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The question is: how can I know who caused the socket close? Is that exception always raised because the remote host closed the connection?

Yes. Anything else *should* cause a connection reset or read timeout, and this is the way the JRE classes themselves behave.

However, the wording of the error message is not encouraging. 'Connection is closed' could mean that the library you're using erroneously throws `EOFException` when using a connection that has been closed by the local application. You would need to review the source code to be sure.